# How can I fix the top of this object so that it doesn't look so much darker than the rest?

Tags: glass

I'm trying to make coffee, but the top just looks so dark in comparison to the rest of the body.
It's like the bottom is super reflective and the top is very absorbant. Notice the darker part looks like some sort of lid laid on top [image: This is Density 150]

[image: This is density 25]

[image: This is density 550, closer to what Blender Guru's tutorial had]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image of your shader nodes.

Comment: Try changing the IOR of your Glass or Refractive Shader (whichever you're using).

Comment: I decided to re-do it out of frustration and after changing the IOR it looked a whole lot better! It also seems like I must've changed something else as well but that's old news... Thanks a lot!